# How to determine QtWebkit Version from source code

Tags: webkit, qtwebkit

I am trying to find the Webkit version within QtWebkit. After building using user agent i can find out, but is there any way to know it from the source code.
There is a file WebKitVersion.h in qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.2\src\3rdparty\webkit\webcore\generated

but in latest Qt5, i could see generate-webkitversion.pl [Source\Webkit\scripts] which reads from /Soure/WebKit/mac/Configurations/Version.xcconfig

what is the deterministic way to find Webkit version

Comment: I found on my own :) Look out for file in 
Source/WebKit/mac/Configurations/Version.xcconfig

find
MAJOR_VERSION = xyz;
MINOR_VERSION = a

This is used by generate-webkitversion in Source/WebKit/Scripts